# how to store messages received from websockets

Tags: database, apache-kafka, websocket, rabbitmq

we are building-up a application with chat system as a part of our service, for that, we are using websockets, as it is easily available on all platform(ios,android,web).

But we need to store all the messages received from the websockets.

We realized websockets are extremely fast, so if fire a query,  for each messages we received through the websockets there might be a

> some chances, some messages would not be store/or get might be
> lost.

let me explain these:

### Case1

so in one-to-one chat, when we receive a message, we store in a variable called  `$msg` and we simply pass this `$msg` to the intended user. So if we add some more logic, like before sending message to user, we could fire a query to store the message, it would take some time, lets say 2sec, or 1 sec, with this logic, **some messages received through the sockets will be lost**,
so we have to have deliver the message as soon as we received.

### Case2

there could be another logic; if we fire a query, after sending the message to the intended user, in that time, there could be a chance `$msg`  variable has changed their value so many times, in just fraction of second.

lets see an example.

lets assume, The variable `$msg` has 'hello' and we pass this `$msg` variable to the function, who stores the message to the database, but as we know,  websockets are extremely fast, there could be chance, the value stored in the $msg, has changed so many times, or we have lost our message 'hello' which we wanted to store.

could we implement the Message Queue(DS MESSAGE QUEUE) in that case, or we should use apache kafka, rabbitmq like services ?

> Note: we already aware with some real time database concepts, provides
> by tech giants, but due to its high cost we are not able to use such
> kind of services.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "high cost"? Plenty of databases support high read/write throughput that are open-source. The "cost" of a server administrator for any database/message queue or training thereof will also be high, and you should weigh that against paying for a hosted service

Comment: if you dispatch a callback function on every websocket receive, there is no way for $msg to be changed, as it is in a different memory scope. how is it being changed?